# Rows of UITableView inside UIScrollView don´t interact when clicking beyond view bounds

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiview, uiscrollview, xib

I have this structure:

- UIScrollView:

  - View
  - View:

    - UITableView

I have set all in a XIB file.

When I click in a row of the UITableView inside the limits of its view in the XIB file, it´s ok (it goes to didSelectRowAtIndexPath method). But if I scroll and then I click in a row of the UITableView beyond the limits of the view size in the XIB file, it does not go to didSelectRowAtIndexPath. What is happening and how should I correct it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

the scroll view delegate methods will get called when you scroll a table view...
i think the code written in side the scroll view delegate methods are creating the problem in your case...
check those methods once...

if it is like so to avoid the execution of code in the delegate methods write these lines

```
if([scrollView isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]])
return;
```

Comment: I don´t override any scroll view delegate methods. Why should I avoid delegate methods? I think that the problem is more related to some size (contentSize of something similar from some view).

Comment: thats fine...what i have told you is restrict delegates of scroll view whem tableview is scrolled if you dont require them on tableview scrolling... could you please post your code

Comment: I have realized that if I set a bigger frame of the view in which the UITableView is contained, I can now access all rows of the table.